# Build and inject files only on change in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp, gulp-changed

I am using gulp-inject and hash-generator to build my javascript files with unique names every time so as to avoid caching issues.Before building I run **gulp-clean** to remove the previously generator javascript files.  The problem is, now every time I run  **npm build**  files are being rebuild even when nothing has changed in the source. I would like to check if something has changed in the source file before running clean and inject. I think **gulp-changed** has the solution, but not sure how to make it work with the hash and cleaning. Part of my implementation looks like this.

```
gulp.task('clean-scripts', function () {
// return del(['./static/js/**/*.js'])
return gulp.src(['./static/js/temp/**/*.js', './static/css/**/style-*.css'], {read: false})
.pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('index', function () {
var target = gulp.src('./templates/base.html');
// It's not necessary to read the files (will speed up things), we're only after their paths: 
var sources = gulp.src(['./static/js/temp/**/*.js', './static/css/'+cssFileName], {read: false}, {relative : true});

return target.pipe(inject(sources))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./templates'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `gulp-rev` or the fork `gulp-revall`. The [`gulp-rev` documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) is pretty bare; check out the [`gulp-revall` documentation](https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all) for a good discussion of what both do and what their differences are (the biggest difference is `gulp-rev-all` checks for changes not only in the files you pass it but also in the files they reference).

Having a little trouble telling exactly how this would fit into the gulp tasks you provided, but here's a working generic example of each plugin:

- **`gulp rev`** will copy everything in `/src` to `/dest-rev`, appending a hash to the filename (default format is `basename-a2c4e6g8i0.ext`; you can add a prefix and/or suffix to the hash, and can change the extension)
- **`gulp revall`** does the same but uses `/dest-revall` (default format is `basename.a2c4e6g8.ext`; you can add a prefix to the hash, transform the basename, transform the file's path, and change the hash length).

The hash depends on the file contents: change the file, and the hash will change. Revert the file, and the hash reverts. (Handy: say someone visits, then you push a changed version with a new hash, then you realize the change was a mistake, revert, and push the reverted version. If the visitor doesn't refresh between the pushes, they'll still be able to rely on their cached copy.)

*In package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
  "del": "^2.2.2",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
  "gulp-rev-all": "^0.8.24"
}
```

*gulpfile.js*

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      del = require('del'),
      rev = require('gulp-rev'),
      revAll = require('gulp-rev-all');

gulp.task('rev', function() {
    del('dest-rev');
    return gulp.src('src/*')
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest-rev'));
});

gulp.task('revall', function() {
    del('dest-revall');
    var rev_all = new revAll();
    gulp.src('src/*')
        .pipe(rev_all.revision())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest-revall'));
});
```

Regardless of whether you use `gulp-rev` or `gulp-revall`, you'll be able to (and will need to) rewrite occurrences of filenames that have been renamed – see the plugins' documentation for details.

Note that I'm deleting the output directories because otherwise the previous versions of the files would be kept. If you *want* to keep those previous versions around, just get rid of the `del` calls.